# Scrapy xpath choose both regular text and link text

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am scraping a table of meeting times. One of the columns holds a meeting status and a link to agenda, if any. I can pull the cells using the following:

Scrapy Shell:

```
things = response.xpath('//tbody/tr')
for thing in things:
   ...:     status_str = item.xpath('.//td[4]').extract()
   ...:     print(status_str)
```

Shell Results:

```
['<td><a href="somelink/agenda1.pdf">Agenda</a></td>']
['<td>Meeting postponed</td>']
['<td><a href="somelink/agenda2.pdf">Agenda</a></td>']
['<td>Postponed</td>']
['<td><a href="somelink/agenda3.pdf">Agenda</a></td>']
['<td>Agenda</td>']
['<td>Agenda</td>']
```

I can successfully choose the a/text() or the text(), but I'd like to choose both. How do I do this?

Comment: Did you try `'./a/text() | ./text()'`?

Comment: I tried the others with no luck. This worked for me. If you want to give it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to implement OR (`|`) as below

```
'./a/text() | ./text()'
```

It means *return child link text OR direct child text node OR both (if both present)*

Answer (score 0):

One method you could use is regex. The following regex will capture any text: `>([A-Za-z ]+)<`.

However, there may be a better method within Scrapy so that you don't have to take the extra step.

Answer (score 0):

You can *stringify* `td` content:

```
   result_str = item.xpath('string(.//td[4])').extract_first()
```